# I'm have trouble deciding odd or even using the argument from command line

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if ( argc%2 == 0 ){
        printf("even\n");}
    else if( argc%2 == 1 ){
        printf("odd\n");}
    else{
        printf("error\n");}
    return 0;  
}
```

The output is always even, but i dont know why.

Comment: What and how many arguments do you pass?

Comment: `argc` is the number of arguments, not the argument itself

Comment: perhaps the use of a debugger would be useful

Comment: I suspect you are trying things like `a.out 1` and `a.out 2`. You are testing the wrong argument. And using the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

`argc` is the number of arguments passed. The first argument for a `main()` function is the program name itself. So first check `argc` to see if there was an argument typed, then convert the argument to integer (it is passed as a string) and then make the odd/even test. Note you only need to do the even test, because if it is not even, it must be odd.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc < 2)                         // check number of arguments
        printf("No argument entered\n");
    else if (!isdigit(argv[1][0]))        // check first char of user arg
        printf("Not a number\n");
    else if (atoi(argv[1]) % 2 == 0)      // convert to int and test
        printf("Even\n");
    else 
        printf("Odd\n");
    return 0;
}
```